# Webpack - Bundling

Tags: json, webpack, bundle

I have following problem. My webpack is bundling files from node_modules. How can I prevent him from doing that? He is doing that, because i import files from node_modules in main.ts, but i have to do this. What am i doing wrong?

**main.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
@NgModule({
    imports: [ BrowserModule ],
    exports: [],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    providers: [],
})
export class AppModule { }
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.json**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry : __dirname + '/src/main.ts',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js','.ts']
    }
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "angular2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --progress"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^2.0.2",
    "typescript": "^2.2.1",
    "typings": "^2.1.0",
    "webpack": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test for .js files and exclude node modules in your loaders, example for using javascript(react) with babel-loader:

```
    {
        test: /.js?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
            presets: [
                'es2015', 'react', 'stage-0',
            ],
    }
    },
```

In your main.js file you can just do `import Module from 'module'` where 'module' is the name of your component. Webpack will bundle it if you refer to it like that.

Example if I want to include React: `import React from 'react'` - no relative paths needed.

Comment: it's angular2 project :)

Comment: I realize that; doesn't change the fact that you can use the above to exclude node_modules in your loaders. It was merely an example :)

Comment: Ok, so I add exclude: /node_modules/, to my ts-loader, but it still goes to node_modules. Actually when i press tsc it's not doing that :) 
There is something wrong with webpack :/

Comment: What do you mean that it goes to your node_modules? Does it compile everything in there to the app.bundle.js?

Comment: Yep, it's compiling everything from node_modules which i import in main.ts :)

Comment: That is the correct behavior, though. If you want to separate your main component as to your external libraries, you need to split them up into two entry points and two outputs.

Comment: But i don't want to bundle files from node_modules ( i think that it shouldn't be bundling, yep? ).

Comment: Up to you, but it's kind of best practice to split up your source and output files - so that when you build something, it takes the dependencies and produces it to another directory. As a project goes, it keeps things clearer. But up to you :)

Comment: Yep, so i don't want to bundling it. How Can i do that? :D It still goes to this node_modules :( :( :(

Comment: If you're using webpack with loaders, bundling is as far as I know necessary since it will 'translate' some elements. I've never used typescript or ts-loader, though.

Comment: But this code has 72k lines of code, when i bundle it.

Comment: Yes, you're using third party libraries; it will be bundled as your sourcecode depends on it

Comment: anyway, even if it has 72k lines of code, is it good? I don't think so :P

Comment: It's normal. The Javascript ecosystem is a mess.

Comment: wtf, cannot believe xD